# alert user when leaving route in Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Ok so i have a component i made up with a form. I would like to alert the user that he has unsaved data (if he has) when the user clicks on another link.
Now if i would not be tied to ember i would put a flag on a change event and add a window unload listener to show the actual message, However,
Since im not really leaving the window this is not getting called.

Is there any Ember event i can attach a handler to? like a change route intent event of some kind

Im interesting in knowing which is the correct event for the leaving route action, not in the something change logic.

ive tried this so far on the didInsertElement( ) method

```
Ember.$("body").on('unload',()=> alert('it works'));     
Ember.$("window").on('unload',()=> alert('it works'));   
Ember.$("body").on('unload','body'()=> alert('it works'));
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the `willTransition` method on your route? That will be the place to do it. Have a read of this guide to [preventing and retrying transitions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/), as well as the `willTransition` method's [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition). Hope that helps!

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Pleased to hear it! Feel free to mark it as answered for anyone else who finds this, and let me know if you'd like any more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [transition event](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition) on route. It's meant to be used for this use case.
There is also action when component is being [destroyed](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_willDestroyElement) but that is meant for teardown.